# Where i can get key codes of devnagri scripts

Tags: java, android, keyboard, keycode

After getting how to create a latin keyboard, now i am planning to create devngari keyboard app. but the problem is that where i can get key codes for devnagari script ?. eg:

```
<Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
<Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
<Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
```

i tried:

```
<Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="क"/>
<Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="त"/>
<Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="ब"/>
```

but it resulted as key code..somebody help me.I have googled, but didn't find , thatswhy Iam here.

Comment: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my time.